# Accessing UI elements from fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have a class which extends fragment class as below:

```
public class FragmentCreateGroup extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ImageView group=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.group_image);//shows error here

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_creategroup, container,false);
    }

}
```

which is associated to the following xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/cr_group_grpname_desc"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/group_image"
        android:layout_width="139dp"
        android:layout_height="144dp"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/cr_group_grpname_input"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cr_group_grpname_desc"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/cr_group_grpname_hint"
        android:inputType="text" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cr_group_creategrp_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:background="@drawable/greenbutton"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/cr_group_creategrp_btn_label" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to access the ImageView in the fragment layout using findViewById(). Since I didn't extend Activity class I was unable to perform this action. Is there any way to access the UI Elements from a non activity class? if any how to perform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the view after you inflate it in onCreateView

```
public class FragmentCreateGroup extends Fragment {

private ImageView group;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_creategroup, container, false);
    group = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.group_image);
    group.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            group.setImageDrawable(); // set image here
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

}

Comment: I need change the ImageView on onClick. how to do that?

Comment: You should make your ImageView global, and then you can access it after you've defined it. I'll edit my answer to show this

Comment: what if I have to access the ImageView from some other activity? How do I get the object of the current active fragment?